# Missing Override annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, github-actions, codeql

Working through some code alerts and came across this note on CodeQL:

```
Missing Override annotation.
```

along with the following description:

```
This method overrides abstractEntity.canEqual; it is advisable to add an Override annotation.
```

I ensured that the respective methods mentioned contained a @Override annotation, and when adding another annotation, the Intellij CE 2023 linter requested it to be removed. In addition, I have tried the following snippet within the effected file and other adjacent annotations:

```
@Getter(onMethod_ = {@Override})
```

I would just like to bypass the message on GitHub Actions as the methods are working as intended.

Comment: Can you show the relevant class as well as its superclass? Also, please show how IntelliJ wants to remove the annotation.

Comment: Please note that lombok's `@Getter` has nothing to do with any `canEqual` method that this is about.

Comment: `canEqual` is made by `@EqualsAndHashCode` (and therefore, `@Data` and `@Value`) - not `@Getter`. I am not familiar with codeQL - lombok generates annotations to mark off the method it makes as 'this is generated code, don't lint it', but some linter tools are badly written and don't take these into account. If you write one yourself and you get an error that you're not overriding when you are, _that_ compiler doesn't have lombok / the class file it's going off of wasn't compiled with lombok on the path.